# Python Multiprocessing or Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

My code

```
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
def print_function(tests):
    while True:
        print tests
        time.sleep(2)


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

for i in range(5):
    a = executor.submit(print_function(i))
```

output
`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...`

but I want out 012345, 012345, 012345...

How can I do this ?

Comment: You are calling your function yourself. You should let the `executor` do that for you. Did you mean: `a = executor.submit(print_function, i)`?

Comment: this is not important I try executor.submit(print_function, i)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve by using threading/multiprocessing to get "012345, 012345, 012345, ..."? Both are means of preemptive concurrency, meaning there is no ordering whatsoever between tasks. The tasks may run in arbitrary order, so each block will give a seemingly random order like "421350"; after many (many) cycles, the ``time.sleep`` will not be sufficient to keep blocks coherent and you might get "0341205". Basically if you want such order, then threading/multiprocessing is very, very likely the wrong tool.

Comment: @JohnettaPeterson: you have tried to edit my answer. Please post a comment instead. You can only [edit] your own posts (the question), not everyone's posts. (That will change over time; once you have enough reputation, you can edit other people's posts).

Comment: I have rolled back yet another edit that erased significant parts of the question. Please be mindful not to destroy questions via edits. It is fine to rework a question to improve it, but it should still be about the fundamentally same issue and not invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
a = executor.submit(print_function(i))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you are calling the function already. Since it has a `while True`, it will never finish and thus `submit()` will never be reached.

The solution is to pass the function as a reference and the argument separately:

```
a = executor.submit(print_function, i)
```

However, notice that you will not get the output you like (`012345`), since a) the range will stop at 4 and b) you kick off only 2 workers and c) the operating system will choose which process to run, so that will be seemingly random (more like `310254`).